# R: ggarrange() "No graphics to replay" error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggarrange() to combine 3 ggplots and am getting the following error message:

```
"In grid.echo.recordedplot(dl, newpage, prefix) : No graphics to replay"
```

My code of one of the plots (they are all the same just different values) and the ggarrange() are below:

```
All_data_80<-All_data[All_data$rh.x == "80H",]
All_data_80<-All_data[All_data$rh_std_num == "80",]
All_data_80<-na.omit(All_data_80)
plot_80<-ggplot
ggplot(data=All_data_80 , aes(x = `Name`, y=`q`, fill=`Name`)) +
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle("Plot Title")+
  geom_col(data=All_data_80[All_data_80$Number=="5",],position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  geom_col(data=All_data_80[All_data_80$Number=="14",],position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  geom_col(data=All_data_80[All_data_80$Number==="95",],position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  xlab("Name")+
  ylab("Percentage")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=8),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.title=element_text(size=12,hjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(face="bold",size=14, hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption=element_text(size=12,hjust = 0.0),
        strip.text = element_text(size=12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank())
plot_80

ggarrange(plot_40, plot_60, plot_80, labels=c("A","B","C"), nrow=1, ncol=3)
```

The output looks like:
[image]

Could anyone help me understand where I am going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: When you run `plot_40`, `plot_60` and `plot_80` separately, do you get individual plots for each one of them? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The plots do get produced individually! I would just like to view them all side by side. I will work on making reproducible data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

You never store any plots in `plot_40`, `plot_60`, or `plot_80`, so there is nothing to plot. You are storing the actual `ggplot` function in them.

**Reproducible example**

```
test <- ggplot2::ggplot
ggpubr::ggarrange(test)
```

This yields:

```
Warning message:
In grid.echo.recordedplot(dl, newpage, prefix) : No graphics to replay
```

**Reasoning**

In your code, this arises because you wrote:

```
plot_80 <- ggplot
*ggplot call*
plot_80
```

So, you store the `ggplot` function in `plot_80`, then you output a plot (but never store it), and then you call `plot_80` (which contains the content of the ggplot function). I think you meant to write it as:

```
plot_80 <- *ggplot call*
```